# SQLite как вывести месяца?

Tags: sql, sqlite

У меня есть запрос считающий зарплату сотрудников за последний полгода по месяцам от текущей даты. Можно ли как-то вместо "Month-1", "Month-2" вывести название месяцев в колонка?

```
SELECT Name,
BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * 0.03 AS '1 Month',
BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * 0.03 AS '2 Month',
BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * 0.03 AS '3 Month',
BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * 0.03 AS '4 Month',
BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * 0.03 AS '5 Month',
BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * 0.03 AS '6 Month'
FROM Employees
```

Comment: Сделайте табличку с соответствием :)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev это я уже сделал, но sqlite не дает сделать подзапрос для конструкции AS, и поэтому я сюда и обратился.

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос условие запроса целиком?  Из нынешнего запроса совершенно ничего не ясно: какие-то дни года зачем-то, магические числа.

Comment: @Ainar-G Отобразить всех сотрудников компании и их зарплаты за полгода(месяца горизонтально)